# Small message box at cursor

Tags: .net, vb.net, cursor, message

I am looking for some sort of message box that occurs at the cursor. Essentially, when I scroll over a label, I want abit of information to display about that label. Once the cursor moves away from the label, the box dissapears. I can't seem to make Google understand me so I was hoping you guys could help me out.

Its like when you hover over a link, this white box appears and dissapears once you move your mouse. What is it called?

Sorry for the really simple question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for a [tooltip](https://web.archive.org/web/20140205185309/http://msdn.microsoft.com:80/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511495.aspx):

> A tooltip is a small pop-up window that labels the unlabeled control being pointed to, such as unlabeled toolbar controls or command buttons.
>
> [image]
>   <sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC76059.png))</sub>

However, they are usually intended for *unlabeled* controls. A label usually is for *describing* another control and as such shouldn't require a tooltip. In fact, the System.Windows.Forms.Label doesn't even offer one.

Comment: Yeah thats it. I don't see why it shouldn't be used for labels.

Comment: @PejmanPoh Because the label is a descriptive text field.  If you need extra descriptive text to describe descriptive text then you are very probably going to end up confusing the user regardless.